# i am facing timeout issues on bamboo for selenium automation suites

Tags: java, selenium, automation

Has anyone faced a similar issue where scripts were failing intermittently just for timeout ,once for locators and sometimes for some other area?

Error:
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@placeholder='Select Key'] (tried for 120 second(s) with 100

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that Selenium failed to find element matching the passed locator, `//*[@placeholder='Select Key']` XPath in this case, to be clickable.
This may be caused by any of the following:

1. There is no element matching the passed locator on that page (the locator is bad)
2. There are several elements matching the passed locator on that page while the first element matching that locator is not clickable, for example disabled etc. (locator is not unique)
3. The element is inside iframe etc.